# How to save plotly offline by running my script

Tags: python, plotly

I am using below code in my jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

print(__version__)

import cufflinks as cf
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','B','C'],'Values':[22,33,45]})
df2.iplot(kind='bar',x='Category',y='Values', asImage=True, filename='bar')
```

Its giving an image to save while running in `notebook`, and i saved this code in `bar.py` and I ran `python bar.py` it's giving me the error `You must be authenticated to generate an image via json.`

I want to run my script which will save my bar plot as image in the same location, I can't use `notebook` because this scripts is going to be in my automation.

Answer (score 1):

The Plotly graphs are generated in HTML+Javascript. When you run in Jupyter Notebook, you're in a web application that runs in the browser already, so it can render them directly.

When running on the command line, it can generate an HTML file with the graph for you, but you'll need to open that in the browser to have it rendered.

The [Plotly Offline](https://plot.ly/python/offline/) documentation page explains this. The text there says that you can save images only when running in Notebook. There seems to be a way to generate an image using online mode - you will need a Plotly account and network access for that.

You might want to consider a different plot library for automated offline work, which does not require network access or running an HTML user agent.

Answer (score 0):

tried this https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/ and volla!

though I had to struggle with orca.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio


print(__version__)

import cufflinks as cf
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_bar(x=df2['Category'],y=df2['Values'])

iplot(fig)
pio.write_image(fig, 'fig1.png')
```

Comment: Neeraj is on the right track using Plotly's orca. OP asked to have it work as a script & not in a notebook though. So comment out lines 4 &14-16 and add back in `df2`defining from OP's code. Launch a Jupyter environment [here](https://github.com/fomightez/orca-plotly-binderized) so there's no struggle with orca.  Click the Jupyter logo to get to the dashboard & make a text file. Paste the code in & then save the code with a `.py` extension in the file name. Back in the dashboard, open a terminal & type `python` followed by the name of the script . Upon completion, you'll see `fig1.png1`.