# How to plot using plotly with offline mode out not in iPython notebooks?

Tags: python, plotly

I need to plot my data using plotly, But this code doesn't give me any result, I display my data, but without any figure:

```
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

    data_t = []

    for mac, dico_data in dict_info.items():
        data_t.append(go.Scatter( x= dico_data['asn'], y= dico_data["time"], name=mac ))
        print (data_t)
    data = data_t
    iplot(data_t)
```

Comment: have you run this in a Jupyter notebook? It seems `plotly` scripts need to be run in a Jupyter notebook. note: `Use plotly.offline.iplot() when working offline in a Jupyter Notebook to display the plot in the notebook.`, src: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/#initialization-for-offline-plotting

Comment: Yes I try offline.plot(data_t) and it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If any of the answers helped solved your question, it would be beneficial if you close your question by accepting the best answer

Comment: If you add in Plotly's orca now you can generate a static image of the plot that doesn't require being in a notebook to then see. All can be done without using notebooks, see my comment below Neeraj Vashistha's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553064/8508004). (You'll note that I am only really using Jupyter there to have a remote server that has orca installed to enable demonstration.) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52188401/8508004) about orca.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Or try using the inline mode in notebooks:

```
py.init_notebook_mode()
```

And if you are using it out of a notebook, try the following example:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

plotly.offline.plot({
    "data": [go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 3, 2, 1])],
    "layout": go.Layout(title="hello world")
}, auto_open=True)
```

Read more in the plotly documentation: https://plot.ly/python/offline/

Comment: It doen't give me any result, figure doesn't appear

Comment: Can you try my added solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**
Due to inbuilt restriction in browser, you need to install

> plotly-extension

**Solution:**
Install it if missing with:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension
```

**Reference:**

1. https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html